# How would you go about finding a basis of matrices in a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Given $4$ spanning $2 \times 2$ matrices, how would you find a basis? Our professor will not let us isomorph them to $\mathbb R^4$. I tried putting them into elementary matrices however I do not know what to do afterwards.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. As a vector space the space of matrices is just $\mathbb{R}^4$, even if the four coordinates are arranged in a matrix rather than a row. So do the usual operations with that notation. Or get clarification from your professor.

Comment: So just treat them as coordinates within the matrix?

Comment: Yes, exactly....

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Can you show that the set 
$$ \bigg\{\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&0
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
0&0
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0\\
1&0
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}\bigg\}$$
is linearly independent? If so, then it must be spanning because $\dim(\mathcal{M}_2(\mathbf{R}))=4$.